# Modify an existing LDAP ObjectClass to include new Attribute

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have an existing LDAP ObjectClass of gosaAccount, used by Fusion Directory, and I am looking to add a new attribute to track the badge numbers of members with this object class. Fairly simple. I was able to use ldapmodify to add the attribute but have had no luck adding the attribute to the gosaAccount object through ldapmodify. Right now I am running into the error `ldap_modify: Invalid syntax (21) additional info: objectclasses: value #0 invalid per syntax` when I attempt to run ldapmodify with an LDIF file with the below contents. What am I missing that would prevent me from modifying this class?

This is the file I used to add the attribute to the schema common name (exposing it to all Schemas/Object Classes)

```
version: 1
dn: cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: (  2.16.840.1.113730.3.1.5
  NAME 'badgeNumber'
  DESC 'Employee Badge Number'
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.36
  SINGLE-VALUE )
```

And this LDIF file is the one used to add that attribute to gosaObject.

```
version: 1
dn: cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: objectclasses
objectclasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.10098.1.2.1.19.6 NAME 'gosaAccount'
  DESC 'Class for GOsa Accounts (v2.6.6)'
  SUP top
  AUXILIARY
  MUST uid
 MAY ( sambaLMPassword $ sambaNTPassword $ sambaPwdLastSet $ gosaDefaultLanguage $ academicTitle $ personalTitle $ dateOfBirth $ sambaBadPasswordCount $ sambaBadPasswordTime $ gender $ gosaLoginRestriction $ badgeNumber ) )
```

Comment: I don't see why you need this step at all, if you've already modified the `gosaAccount` definition successfully. If the step above succeeded you would lose all the other objectclasses. Unclear why you're even trying.

Comment: That's the thing -- I added an attribute to cn=schema, but not to the objectClass itself. Let me post the first file I used to define the attribute.

Comment: Surely you need to add the new attribute to the `may` attributes of the object `cn=gosaAccount,cn=objectclasses,cn=schema,cn=config`. Not to this object?

Comment: Yes, instead of finding the cn for gosaAccount, Fusion Directory includes its own command line utility that I can use to modify existing schema entries, over ldapmodify. By supplying it with a modified schema, the attribute has been added.

Comment: Could you please post the exact command and LDIF used by Fusion Directory behind the scene?